# Kids in advanced scifi school novel series?

Tags: story-identification, novel, robots, childrens-novel

Okay, I remember this being sold in a Christian bookstore, but it may or may not have been Christian themed. Basically these kids were part of an advanced school in a futuristic society, and went on various adventures across space fighting evil, they may have had super powers. There was a robot on the team. Definitely a series of novels, I also think it had stories on tape and possibly a film or cartoon. I remember seeing illustrations of the characters. I was a kid in the 90s, and it seemed a bit old at the time.

Thanks!